# Does it make sense to use completableFuture together with CRUD when working with WebFlux?

Tags: spring, webflux

I'm just starting to learn webFlux.I'm just starting to learn webplus and I'm interested in question.If it makes sense to use completableFuture together with CRUD operations?

That is , let 's say i have `RestService`:

```
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
public class personController {
    personServiceImpl personService;

    @GetMapping("/all")
    Flux<Person> getAllPerson(){
        return personService.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public Mono<Person> post(@RequestBody Person user) {
        System.out.println("inside***************");
        return personService.saveOrUpdate(user);
    }
}
```

Does it make sense to make such a service for processing requests?

**personServiceImpl**:

```
public class personServiceImpl implements personService{

  personRepository repository;

  @Override
  public Mono<Person> saveOrUpdate(Person person) {
     CompletableFuture<Person> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
           repository.save(person);
           return person;
     });

     return Mono.fromFuture(future);
     
  }

  @Override
  public Mono<Person> findByEmail(String email) {

     CompletableFuture<Person> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {

            Person person = repository.findByEmail(email);
            return person;
     });
     return Mono.fromFuture(future);
     
  }
}
```

Or just regular calls without Future will work better?

```
public class personServiceImpl implements personService{

  personRepository repository;

  @Override
  public Mono<Person> saveOrUpdate(Person person) {
     return repository.save();
  }

  @Override
  public Mono<Person> findByEmail(String email) {

     return repository.findByEmail();
  }
}
```

I will be glad if you can help me understand whether Future makes sense here .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it does not make sense. WebFlux is already non-blocking which means that your application will be capable of handling other requests / processes while waiting for the Database to return the results of your query.

`Future`s are more suited to very expensive processes that might take seconds or even minutes. In your cases, you are performing simple Database queries that should return a result within a few milliseconds so you are not really benefiting from the `CompletableFuture` approach and it might even be counterproductive.

Just stick to WebFlux `Mono`s and `Flux`s and get rid of the `CompletableFuture` approach. Start simple and do not try to optimize your code for no reason. Go with the simplest code you can implement that actually works and do not over-complicate it unless you really have the need.